# Как сделать эффект текста, обрезанного фоном как на скрине?

Tags: html, css

[image: Скрин]

Нужно сделать будто текст обрезан фоном, каким методом лучше это реализовать?

Comment: а что вы уже попробовали?

Comment: Общую идею посмотрите [тут](https://webref.ru/layout/html5-css3/background/multiple), ничего сложного. Второй вариант с помощью Photoshop, что тоже очень просто. Делать не буду, напраления мысли достаточно.

Comment: Я бы вырезал планету из макета вместе с эффектом и позиционировал над текстом, возможно понадобится z-indexю Или же как вариант поигрался бы с linear-gradient на тексте

Comment: пример - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/rb2ko93s/

Answer (score 1):

Как например и наглядный пример к общим рекомендациям и ответам (использовать слои из фона, текста и самой планеты):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.box {
  background: #000 url(https://coubsecure-s.akamaihd.net/get/b106/p/coub/simple/cw_timeline_pic/ff77a61c166/daf19b6c402918c47de82/big_1473285305_1382492342_image.jpg) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  color:#fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  
}

.box h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 10px 0px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.mars {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  right: -10px;
  bottom: -50%;
  width: 70%;
}

.mars img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float:right;
  z-index: 3;
}

.mars:after {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom:10px;
  box-shadow: -25px -25px 300px #fd3001;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-inner">
    <h1>Путешествие</h1>
    <span>на красную планету</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="mars">
    <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/elderscrolls/images/a/a3/TESBloodmoonIcon.png/revision/latest?cb=20151229100452&path-prefix=it" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Несколько вариантов есть:

**Картинка**
Ну думаю понятно, просто это всё добавить картинкой.

**Слой и градиент**
первый слой - фон, второй слой - текст, третий слой планета. И на второй слой, текст, мы добавляем градиент.. Но получается, что текст будет svg'ный.

**Снова слои**
Такие же слои как и во втором варианте, только без градиента на тексте.
Градиент будет идти уже от слоя планеты, т.е. градиент будет поверх текста.